# Galaxy Tab 3, turning on USB Debugging crashes USB driver

Tags: android, driver, galaxy-tab, usb-debugging

Can't get the device drivers working 100% for a Galaxy Tab 3.

The driver install seems to complete normally. Initially, the tablet appears to be discovered normally, and appears OK in the 'file system', where I can browse through the tablet's folders in the usual way. However, 'adb devices' can't see the tablet.

But then driver crashes **after I turn on USB Debugging for the tablet**.

I have the minimum system requirements, though the PC is rather old (2007).
Win XP, SP3, Windows Media Player 10, DirectX 9.
Brand new Galaxy Tab 3, model SM-T210R, Android 4.1.2.
Fresh download of the Eclipse-based developer's kit.

I have been using this as a guide:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

I have tried three different drivers, and they all show the same misbehavior:

- Kies (bloated tool)
- Samsung USB Driver for Mobile Phones 1.5.14
- Samsung USB Driver for Mobile Phones 1.3.15

Pretty frustrating. Any help appreciated....

Comment: Galaxy Tab 3 is a new device so I guess you'll need a recent release of Samsung USB drivers, like v1.5.33.

Comment: do you have a link for that version?

Comment: Go [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=11633550#post11633550), John. Let me know if you still have problem with the GT3 after installing the USB drivers.

Comment: Did the link I provided help you?

Comment: No, no luck. I wound up buying a modern PC, which I needed in any case, to run the Android development tools. I had better luck there.